# LibGDX: GooglePlayService failed to sign in

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-services

i want to sign in to GooglePlayService and display a leaderboard. 
My class looks like this:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.GameHelperListener;

import controller.ActionResolver;
import controller.Liiinda;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements ActionResolver, GameHelperListener{

    private GameHelper gameHelper;
    Handler uiThread;
    InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        config.useAccelerometer = false;
        config.useCompass = false;

        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ad_id));
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
          @Override
          public void onAdLoaded() {

          }
          @Override
          public void onAdClosed() {

          }
        });



        interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        if (gameHelper == null) {
            gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_ALL);
            gameHelper.enableDebugLog(true);
        }

        gameHelper.setup(this);


        initialize(new Liiinda(this), config);
    }

    @Override
    public void showInterstitialAds() {

        try {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        interstitialAd.show();
                    }
                    else {
                        AdRequest interstitialRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                        interstitialAd.loadAd(interstitialRequest);
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void writeHighscore(int highscore) {
        SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("GAME", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putInt("HIGHSCORE", highscore);
        editor.commit();

    }

    @Override
    public int readHighscore() {
        SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("GAME", 0);
        return pref.getInt("HIGHSCORE", 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void compareScore(int score) {
        if (score > readHighscore()) {
            writeHighscore(score);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        gameHelper.onStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        gameHelper.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
        gameHelper.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getSignedInGPGS() {
        return gameHelper.isSignedIn();
    }

    @Override
    public void loginGPGS() {
        try {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("test", "Try to login...");
                    gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
                }
        });
        } catch (final Exception ex) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void submitScoreGPGS(int score) {
        if (getSignedInGPGS()){
            Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(gameHelper.getApiClient(), getString(R.string.leaderboard_highscore), score);
        }
        else{
            // Maybe sign in here then redirect to submitting score?
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void getLeaderboardGPGS() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (getSignedInGPGS()) {
                    startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient(), getString(R.string.leaderboard_highscore)), 9002);
                }
                else {
                    loginGPGS();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInFailed() {
        Log.e("test", "GameServiceInterface sign in failed");

    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInSucceeded() {
        Log.e("test", "GameServiceInterface sign in succeeded");

    }

    @Override
    public void openMarket(){
        android.net.Uri uri = android.net.Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + this.getPackageName());
        Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        try {
          startActivity(goToMarket);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, android.net.Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + this.getPackageName())));
        }
    }


}
```

I have created and released my leaderboard and set my game to beta-phase + added myself as tester.
But i don't understand why i get the message: "Failed to sign in. Please check your network connection and try again"

The log looks like this:

```
11-16 15:48:49.575: D/Liiiinda(15564): Tentative to login...
11-16 15:48:49.575: D/GameHelper(15564): GameHelper: beginUserInitiatedSignIn: resetting attempt count.
11-16 15:48:49.575: D/GameHelper(15564): GameHelper: Starting USER-INITIATED sign-in flow.
11-16 15:48:49.575: D/GameHelper(15564): GameHelper: beginUserInitiatedSignIn: continuing pending sign-in flow.
11-16 15:48:49.575: D/GameHelper(15564): GameHelper: resolveConnectionResult: trying to resolve result: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{41c86a78: android.os.BinderProxy@41c86868}}
11-16 15:48:49.575: D/GameHelper(15564): GameHelper: Result has resolution. Starting it.
11-16 15:48:49.605: I/AndroidInput(15564): sensor listener tear down
11-16 15:48:49.605: I/AndroidGraphics(15564): paused
11-16 15:48:49.715: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(15564): reportFullscreenMode on inactive InputConnection
11-16 15:48:54.115: D/GameHelper(15564): GameHelper: onActivityResult: req=RC_RESOLVE, resp=SIGN_IN_FAILED
11-16 15:48:54.115: D/GameHelper(15564): GameHelper: onAR: responseCode=SIGN_IN_FAILED, so giving up.
11-16 15:48:54.115: W/GameHelper(15564): disconnect() called when client was already disconnected.
11-16 15:48:54.185: D/GameHelper(15564): GameHelper: Notifying LISTENER of sign-in FAILURE (error)
```

My Manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="jimpasoft.game.liiinda.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="jimpasoft.game.liiinda.android.AndroidLauncher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Anyone got an idea?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found the mistake:

In my Developer Console instead of using the package "***.***.mygame.android", i used the core package "***.***.mygame"